# using css selector for imacros with conditions

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors, imacros

Want to know if conditional css selector works with iMacros? I want to run a web scraper. The below selector is working with Web Scrape chrome extension, but it doesn't work with iMacros.

Selector:

```
div.s-expand-height:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), .celwidget div.s-item-container:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), div.s-include-content-margin:has(span.a-price.a-text-price)
```

I tried this with iMacros in below formats, but not working

**Format 1**

```
TAG POS=7 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"s-expand-height:has(span a-price.a-text-price), celwidget s-item-container:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), s-include-content-margin:has(span.a-price.a-text-price)" EXTRACT=TXT
```

**Format 2**

```
TAG POS=7 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"div.s-expand-height:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), .celwidget div.s-item-container:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), div.s-include-content-margin:has(span.a-price.a-text-price)" EXTRACT=TXT
```

My complete iMacros script looks like this.

```
SET !DATASOURCE E:\imacros\urllist1.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS={{!COL2}}

TAG POS=7 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"s-expand-height:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), .celwidget s-item-container:has(span.a-price.a-text-price), s-include-content-margin:has(span.a-price.a-text-price)" EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"s-expand-height s-include-content-margin s-border-bottom s-latency-cf-section" EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=E:\imacros FILE=data.csv
```

Comment: Hum, Qt sounds interesting, open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum and I would be willing to do some Testing/Digging... FCI not mentioned (or you would have gotten a '+1' from me), but you have a 'TAG SELECTOR' Mode in v10.x for CR...

Comment: Hum, not interested apparently, fair enough..., but if you "change your mind", you know "where to find me", ah-ah...! (I'm the Mod and Tech Guru on the iMacros Forum...) - I don't or very rarely answer Qt's on this Forum, ... explained in my Profile... - But I honestly don't think you'll get any Help/Answer(s) on this Forum, when I say that a Qt is "interesting", that means "it's way too above the Level you can expect on SOF", ah-ah...!

Comment: @chivracq I just posted this question to the iMacros forum as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, + for anybody "interested", I posted a Solution in #OP's [parallel Thread](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31311&p=86551#p86551) on the iMacros Forum using mostly 'Relative Positioning' to achieve what I "think" I understood, the Functionality that $OP wants, applied to the Website and Webpages they gave as Example...

Here is the "short" Script I posted, the whole Thread contains (much) more Info and a "full" Script with all Debug Info/Technique(s) I used...:

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2

'SET !LOOP 1

TAB T=1
'URL GOTO=https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A%211063498%2Cn%3A284507%2Cn%3A289814&lo=image&qid=1606931446&ref=lp_289814_il_ti_kitchen

'Extract 'Original Price' (Striked through):
'TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:$14.95
'TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"a-price a-text-price"&&DATA-A-STRIKE:"true"&&TXT:$*$* EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT NULL
'TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"a-price a-text-price"&&DATA-A-STRIKE:"true"&&TXT:$*$* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"a-price a-text-price"&&DATA-A-STRIKE:"true"&&TXT:$*$* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Orig_Price EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.split('$'); y=x[1]; z='$'+y; z;")

'Extract 'Discount Price':
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:"a-price"&&TXT:$*$* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Discount_Price EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.split('$'); y=x[1]; z='$'+y; z;")

'Extract 'Description':
'TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:Genuine<SP>Instant<SP>Pot<SP>Tempered<SP>Glass<SP>Lid,<SP>9* EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET Descr EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z=s.trim(); z;")

PROMPT LOOP:<SP>_{{!LOOP}}_<BR><BR>Descr:<SP>_{{Descr}}_<BR>Discount_Price:<SP>_{{Discount_Price}}_<BR>Original_Price:<SP>_{{Orig_Price}}_
```

Script written and tested using iMacros for FF v8.8.2, PM v26.3.3, Win10_x64.
(Needs to be looped...)